# Aura framework ternary operator render issue

Tags: javascript, lightning, aura

I don't know why this expression is not getting rendered. I am trying to append the css class based on status value on the TR.

```
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
                                <tr class="(!item.Status} !='Active' ? 'css_red': 'net_css_green')">
                                    <td >
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" ><span>{!item.Name}</span></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td >
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" >{!item.Type}</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </aura:iteration>
```

This is how it is rendered in browser. Instead of rendering the expression, whole code is append as class value. why?

[image: This is the how it is coming in brower.]

Answer (score 2):

You missed the markup with brace.

```
<tr class="{!item.Status !='Active' ? 'css_red': 'net_css_green'}">
```

Comment: I did a silly mistake here, I didn't knew, this whole ternary operation should end with "}". I have few doubt, first, how is this rendered as JS or how?, second, does aura process it and generate html for such expression.

Comment: @NaveenTulsi your mistake was that your expression should be enclosed in `{!` and `}`. Your expression should lie inside this "evaluator". "this whole ternary operation should end with '}'" is a wrong statement.